# Codeigniter : Getting an error message Undefined property: stdClass

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on my program using Codeigniter. I try to count data between two dates. But i got an error like this.

> A PHP Error was encountered 
>   Severity: Notice 
>   Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$umum 
>   Filename: admin/periode-rekam.php 
>   Line Number: 66

Controller :

```
public function perioderekam()
{
    [.....]

    $data['umum'] = $this->a_model->hitung_umum($tgl_awal,$tgl_akhir);
    $this->template->admin('admin/periode-rekam',$data);
}
```

Model :

```
public function hitung_umum($tgl_awal,$tgl_akhir)
{
    $sql ="SELECT COUNT(tb_mengambil.kode_kategori) AS total
    FROM tb_mengambil
    JOIN tb_kategori ON tb_mengambil.kode_kategori = tb_kategori.kode_kategori
    WHERE tb_mengambil.tgl_resep between '$tgl_awal' and '$tgl_akhir'
    ORDER BY tgl_resep DESC;";
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

EDITED : IT SOLVED ALREADY. Here the answer. 

Because i pass echo $isi->umum on my View, i need to change my query on model like this.

```
public function hitung_umum($tgl_awal,$tgl_akhir)
{
    $sql ="SELECT COUNT(tb_mengambil.kode_kategori) AS umum
    FROM tb_mengambil
    JOIN tb_kategori ON tb_mengambil.kode_kategori = tb_kategori.kode_kategori
    WHERE tb_mengambil.tgl_resep between '$tgl_awal' and '$tgl_akhir'
    ORDER BY tgl_resep DESC;";
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

And I put code like this on my View :

```
<tr>
   <th colspan="8">Total Kategori Umum</th>
   <th colspan="2"><?php foreach ($umum as $isi){
                    echo ($isi->umum);}?>
   </th>
</tr>
```

I also tried `<?php echo $umum; ?>` but it also got me an error ' Array to string conversion'

Comment: `print_r($umum);` and check in view

Comment: according to the query it has only `$isi->total`

Comment: @splash58 oh god!!!! i didnt realized it!._.

Comment: Please **never** put `[SOLVED]` within your title.  Instead, post your answer below as soon as allowed and "accept" it.  Edited  Thanks.